# How do you convert a string representation of a UTF-16 byte sequence to UTF-8 in Python?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, utf-16

I'm creating a program that will read .rtf files. .rtf files are encoded in ASCII, but represent non-ASCII characters with an escape sequence followed by two numbers representing a UTF-16 double-byte. For example, "これは日本語。" is represented as "\'82\'b1\'82\'ea\'82\'cd\'93\'fa\'96\'7b\'8c\'ea\'81\'42".

For the purposes of my program, the code page is always "cpg1252".

How do I convert the "\'xx" sequences to a UTF-8 string? I tried playing around with the codecs, but all I got was gibberish.

Comment: RTF uses *signed integers* to encode UTF-16 code units, actually, prefixed by `\u` and followed by a replacement character.

Comment: There are no instances of "\u" in my .rtf files. Are the "\'xx" not UTF-16 then?

Comment: I doubt it. The tex you gave, encoded to UTF-16 little-endian (which is what all MS products use), would be `53 30 8c 30 6f 30 e5 65 2c 67 9e 8a 02 30`. The data you gave has no correlation with that.

Comment: According to the RTF 'standard' (what MS published is a little muddy in places), the text you have would be represented as `\u12371?\u12428?\u12399?\u26085?\u26412?\u-30050?\u12290?` instead (using `?` as the 'replacement character').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have [*Shift-JIS* data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS) inside [code-page escapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format#Character_encoding); you can extract the marked-up bytes and decode those:

```
import re
from binascii import unhexlify

cp_escapes = re.compile(r"\'([0-9a-fA-F]{2})")

def extract_cp_escapes(data):
    return unhexlify(''.join(marked_bytes.findall(data)))
```

then decode; Shift-JIS is codepage 932 on Windows:

```
>>> text = r"\'82\'b1\'82\'ea\'82\'cd\'93\'fa\'96\'7b\'8c\'ea\'81\'42"
>>> extract_cp_escapes(text)
'\x82\xb1\x82\xea\x82\xcd\x93\xfa\x96{\x8c\xea\x81B'
>>> print extract_marked_bytes(text).decode('cp932')
これは日本語。
```

You can decode that to another codec like UTF-8 if you need to.

It *may* be possible that the exact code page used is also encoded in the RTF document, but I am out of time to research that.